# PHP is failing to create mySQL record via form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been setting up my first form/PHP/mySQL combo using info from different sites (including this one) and running it with MAMP on my local server. Although the webpage always connects to the target DB successfully it hasn't been inputting the data I type into the MySQL table (I am checking with phpMyAdmin).

You may see some stuff commented out of `insert.php`, this was stuff I had previously tried but didn't work.

form on `index.php`

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
        Diet Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        Your Rating: <select type="int" name="rating">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select><br/>
        Type: BodyBuilding<input type="radio" name="type" value="BodyBuilding"> Weight Loss<input type="radio" name="type" value="Weight Loss"><br/>
        Description: <input type="text" name="descr"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
```

`insert.php` that webpage sends form data to

```
<?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'diet');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Could not use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
    }
        /*$sql="INSERT INTO diet (name, rating, type, descr)
        VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[rating]','$_POST[type],'$_POST[descr]')";*/

        $sql = "INSERT INTO diet ('name', 'rating', 'type', 'descr') VALUES ('$name','$rating','$type','$descr', NOW())";

    if (!$link) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
?>
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to insert 5 values in 4 rows.

Comment: Where is your POST data?

Comment: i dont see `mysql_query`

Comment: is mysql_query not for retrieval?

Comment: would 2 radio buttons require 2 separate entries? I was using a SET field in the DB for them..

Comment: @Alez Actually the OP is trying to put 5 values into 4 columns. :)

Comment: ok i have corrected the 5 values in 4 rows (changed from radio button to drop down menu)

Comment: Where are you executing the `$sql` statement? That seems to be missing as @DrixsonOseña pointed out.

Comment: Now that I see it. There is more than 5-6 things wrong in this query. Not to mention OP is using old, outdated & vulnerable mysql_ functions

Comment: I understand this code my be vulnerable to 'injections' but its my first attempt so I'd be delighted if I could even get it working :)

Comment: Try using PDO. It ships with PHP 5.1 and later. What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: I'm probably completely wrong but I thought by defining $sql that would execute it? After all, $link/$db_selected aren't explicitly executed and it seems to work fine?

Comment: I'll check out PDO, I'm above 5.1 anyways (5.4 I think)

Comment: Thanks for the PDO tip btw jk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PDO example. I don't know what `Now()` represents for you (probably an insert date) but I think you can figure out how to add it.

```
$dbhost = 'YOUR_SERVER';
$dbuser = 'YOUR_USERNAME';
$dbpass = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
$dbname = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$name = $_POST[name];
$rating = $_POST[rating];
$type = $_POST[type];
$desc = $_POST[descr];

if ($conn)
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO diet (name, rating, type, descr) VALUES(:name, :rating, :type, :desc)";
        $insert = $conn->prepare($query);
        $insert->bindValue(":name",$name); 
        $insert->bindValue(":rating",$rating); 
        $insert->bindValue(":type",$type); 
        $insert->bindValue(":desc",$desc); 

        $insert->execute();         
    }
    /* Free connection resources. */
    $conn = null;
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

[Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: Tried all other solutions and this is the only one that added a row! I've installed PDO and will be sticking with it from now on. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysqli instead of mysql.  Even better if you use it with parameterized queries.
This will automatically protect against sql injections.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'diet');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); // open connection

if ($mysqli->connect_error) { // check if connection opened correctly
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// get $_POST vars
$name = $_POST[name];
$rating = $_POST[rating];
$type = $_POST[type];
$desc = $_POST[descr];

$sql="INSERT INTO diet (name, rating, type, descr) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"; // create sql query string

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init(); // initialize sqli statement
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { // prepare sqli statement
    $stmt->bind_params("ssss", $name, $rating, $type, $desc); // bind values to the 4 '?', also stating that each is a string ("ssss")
    $stmt->execute(); // execute statement
    $stmt->close(); // close statement
}
$mysqli->close(); // close connection
```

Comment: The OP has PDO available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the actual `$sql` by using either `mysql_query` or using `mysqli_query`.

You should use something like this

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO diet (name, rating, type, descr)
    VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[rating]','$_POST[type],'$_POST[descr]')";
 mysql_query($sql, $link)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you have some sql injection vulnerabilities there.

Comment: I recommend Prepared Statements but this is so the author can get his code working.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$name=htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
$rating=htmlentities($_POST['rating'], ENT_QUOTES);
$type=htmlentities($_POST['type'], ENT_QUOTES);
$descr=htmlentities($_POST['descr'], ENT_QUOTES);
sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO diet ('name', 'rating', 'type', 'descr') VALUES ('".$name."','".$rating."','".$type."','".$descr."'");
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` could also be used

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an **error in your `$sql`**. Better would be (too many arguments or something like this):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO diet ('name', 'rating', 'type', 'descr') VALUES ('$name','$rating','$type','$descr')";
```

Second, you need to put the data in the table. You only put the SQL Command in a local attribute. Try it this way (with **mysql_query**):

```
mysql_query($sql)
```

If you have some trouble, you could ask for a mysql error:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

You could also log in you phpMyAdmin and try to put the sql manual in it (to find errors in your sql syntax).